# AG normal map to RGB normal map

Tags: node-editor, normal-map

I'm trying to convert ag normal maps (alpha is red channel, green is green channel, blue channel derived from a and g through some formula) to standard normal map (tangent space).
Nvidia's Windows Texture Viewer gives this formula "Normal map AG [dR = sA; dG = sG; dB = sqrt (1.0 - dR*dR - dG*dG); dA = 255]", but I'm more artistically declined than math or programming and failed to recreate this with shader nodes. thanks in advance.
[image: this plane should look like the plane on the right]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This tree reproduces the function you describe:

[image]

It could be made smaller, but I hope this is more self-explanatory. Note that this is Non-Color data, set in the input image.

Comment: I'm not gonna pretend I understand this, but it's so cool what you can do with nodes :).